# jQuery does not work propperly into mini cart WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I faced a weird problem with the mini cart onto the Woocommerce project. We should create the increment/decrement quantity section into the mini cart. My responsibility frontend part of this feature. It's easy-peasy, isn't it?  I created the simple input field:

```
<div class="cart_col_count">
   <div class="quantity-btn-group d-flex">
    <div class="pro-qty">
        <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1"/>
        <span class="inc qty-btn">+</span>
        <span class= "dec qty-btn">-</span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I used a really simple Jquery code for changing the value:

```
$(".qty-btn").on("click", function() {
           var $button = $(this);
           var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
      if ($button.text() == "+") {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
         } else {
      if (oldValue > 0) {
           var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
         } else {
          newVal = 0;
       }
     }
  $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
});
```

But it does not work properly. When I add some products in the cart the mini cart updating with ajax. And now when trying to change the value of the input nothing happens. There are no errors in the console. It feels like Jquery does not see classes after updating the mini cart. But now when I refresh the page the plus / minus buttons start work properly.

I understand that the reason is in the mechanism for updating the mini cart when adding products. But I don't know how to fix it. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Doesn't WooCommerce come with this functionality already? If quantity is available on a product then WC will show this control...

Comment: @NathanielFlick The issue is not about WooCommerce functionality. But if such a question arose, I will answer. Our project is highly customized, products have custom price fields, and so on. Internal functionality is not suitable. But this is not the question. I have problems with the frontend.

Comment: You need to update the data through WooCommerce API here https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction, check out the docs https://docs.woocommerce.com/ and also this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-or-update-cart-quantity-threw-api/